# Connected componentes of $X=\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup} A_n\cup \{(0,0),(0,1)\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I have to find the connected components of $X=\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup} A_n\cup \{(0,0),(0,1)\}$, where $A_n=\{\frac{1}{n}\}\times [0,1]$, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Well, first of all, i know that if i consider $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$, their connected component are $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\{(0,1)\}$ respectively. But, are those the only ones? If they are, how should i prove that? if i fixed $ n \in\mathbb{N}$ , is $A_n$ a connected space? Because if that is correct, can i look for, for example, given $x$ in $A_n$, his connected component?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316235/for-each-n-in-mathbbn-consider-a-n-1-n-times-0-1-and-let-x-big?rq=1

Comment: if anybody could post another answer, i will be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All $A_n$ are connected (homeomorphic to $[0,1]$). All $A_n$ are closed-and-open (clopen) in $X$.

Suppose $C \subseteq X$ is connected, and it intersects at least one $A_n$ non-emptily. Then $C \cap A_n$ is clopen and non-empty in $C$, and so must equal $C$ when $C$ is connected. So $C = A_n$. So the $A_n$ are maximal connected subsets and so are components.

The components of $X$ form a disjoint cover of $X$, for any $X$. As the remaining two points (all but the $A_n$) are as a subset disconnected (as any finite set of more than 1 point in a metric space), the singletons $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\{(0,1\}$ must be the remaining components. Done.